# Normalized to 100 data within groups

Tags: r, normalization

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Var Trait   Value
0   Trait1  42.26
1   Trait1  41.81
2   Trait1  41.21
0   Trait2  47.82
1   Trait2  51.44
2   Trait2  51.42
0   Trait3  10.27
1   Trait3  10.63
2   Trait3  10.14
```

I would like to add a forth column with normalized to 100 data calculated like this for each trait and var1:

(42.26/42.26)*100=**100**

(41.81/42.26)*100=**98.93**

(41.21/42.26)*100=**97.51**

For trait 2 and var1=1, Value is larger than var1=0 Value so in this case row 5 will be calculated like this:
(47.82/51.44)*100=**92.94**

Comment: Or just `with(df, ave(Value, Trait, FUN = function(x) x/max(x)*100))`

Comment: Thanks very much for the wonderful suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is data.table:

```
data[, col4:= (Value/max(Value))*100, by= Trait]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using *dplyr*

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Trait) %>% 
  mutate(Result = Value/max(Value) * 100)

# Output
# Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
# Groups: Trait [3]
# 
#     Var  Trait Value    Result
#   (int) (fctr) (dbl)     (dbl)
# 1     0 Trait1 42.26 100.00000
# 2     1 Trait1 41.81  98.93516
# 3     2 Trait1 41.21  97.51538
# 4     0 Trait2 47.82  92.96267
# 5     1 Trait2 51.44 100.00000
# 6     2 Trait2 51.42  99.96112
# 7     0 Trait3 10.27  96.61336
# 8     1 Trait3 10.63 100.00000
# 9     2 Trait3 10.14  95.39040
```

Comment: Does mutate create a new column?

Answer (score 2):

Or with standard R:

```
dat$Normalized <- (dat$Value / ave(dat$Value, dat$Trait, FUN = max)) * 100
> dat
  Var  Trait Value Normalized
1   0 Trait1 42.26  100.00000
2   1 Trait1 41.81   98.93516
3   2 Trait1 41.21   97.51538
4   0 Trait2 47.82   92.96267
5   1 Trait2 51.44  100.00000
6   2 Trait2 51.42   99.96112
7   0 Trait3 10.27   96.61336
8   1 Trait3 10.63  100.00000
9   2 Trait3 10.14   95.39040
```